# Is flipping the confirm and quit buttons a good idea on quit dialogs?

Tags: close

Is flipping the confirm and quit buttons a good idea on quit dialogs?
Sorry if it's too broad but couldn't think of any other way to phrase it.

[mockup in js](http://jsbin.com/EgUXUjo/1/edit?html,output)

Inspired by [this flash game(15 Mb)](http://notdoppler.com/strikeforceheroes2.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. Inconsistency generally leads to confusion and frustration and little else.

UX Movement has a couple of articles that provide more details (albeit lacking in research) and offer a good alternative approach:

1. [Always put the confirmation button in the bottom right corner](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-ok-buttons-in-dialog-boxes-work-best-on-the-right/)
2. [Switch the *emphasis* of the buttons if you want to attract users' attention toward a cancellation option (because the confirmation option is permanent)](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/the-visual-weight-of-primary-and-secondary-action-buttons/)

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with link #1.  Having used Windows for so many years, convention is *very* strong in this scenario.  it is unnatural to me for OK to be on the right.  I would also say that the relationship between "OK" and "Cancel" is not necessarily Primary->Secondary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea. 
Users never read

- click on quit and see nothing happening
- click again without reading the cancel label and they are back to first step.

This approach will give user frustration not understanding why his action do nothing. He will have to do it again a couple of time before seeing the change. 
 The more basic approach of a very different dialogs for confirmation is well known and will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Users have a tendency to remember the user interface by the position of the UI elements rather than specific labels like text or icon. This is partly due to muscle memory, and partly due to the fact that position of UI elements should not be influenced by other factors. If you do decide to change the position, then it must be something that is easily noticeable by the user or you'll increase the likelihood of them making an unintended decision without even realizing it until they have already performed the action.